Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES) con Spring Boot
Este es el código del aplication:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/visionova
spring.datasource.username=visionova
spring.datasource.password=visionova

  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: visionova
  MYSQL_USER: visionova
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: visionova
  MYSQL_DATABASE: visionova

Estes son mis ficheros de docker-compose y parte del aplication.propierties de mi proyecto en spring boot. Sin querer borre el contenedor, y al volver a levantarlo, me dio el error ese, y a pesar de borrar todo lo del contenedor sigue sin funcionar.
El error completo es el siguiente:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'visionova'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:439)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:46)


Por favor, pon el error completo en la publicación usando el botón editar. Hasta ahora el error solo es de conexión, verifica las credenciales y el datasource. Muestra el datassource url y el driver

el usuario que has declarado es visionovapero el error indica que estás intentando logarte como root... parece un problema de configuración en la url

Listo he editado para que se vea el error completo y añadí alguna cosa más del propierties

Saludos. Crea un nuevo usuario con las credenciales y acceso necesarios para usarlo en tu proyecto; estás usando el root y este de manera remota no tienes habilitado se le permita el acceso. Debes crear un usuario o habilitar al root el acceso remoto (moviendo configuración de tu MySQL en el servidor).
